# Help me with corrupt video mp42

Tags: mp4, hevc, h265

Hello I have one corrupted video file created with Chinese Camera DV4K_V23.

I created one small sample video from this camera and I uploaded it for someone to help me, to decipher exactly which encoding and creating tool they used to create the mp4 output video.

As I see in the hex editor it's something with the version 20032014. Its Hevc x265

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/avc1/mp42)
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main@L5@High
Codec ID                                 : hvc1
Codec ID/Info                            : High Efficiency Video Coding
```

Could you help me to remux this video and to get identical video and did they use ffmpeg or they used some other encoder?

Here is the sample video file

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dq1ibBxLcIcDcZ9V2udr6ulVGnVgqOA9?usp=sharing
```